# Need to divide 8tb directory into 4 directories

Tags: linux

I have a directory called BigDataDirectory which has plenty of files and all of it in total adds up to 8tb.

I am trying to upload to our server and want to make sure I can divide the folder into four parts so I have four folders of about 2tb each.

I tried the split command but it doesn't seem to be working
nohup split -b 2T BigDataDirectory "Directory" &

Could you tell me just a simple way to divide my directory/folder into multiple parts?

Comment: The `split` command is to split files. What you seem to want is to move files from one big directory into 4 smaller directories. Is that it? How many files are there and do they have very different sizes or do they all have a similar size?

Comment: Yes, i would like to do that. It has about 1000 files.

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are of a similar size or if the total directory size doesn't need to be very precise, you could do it with these fun commands.

It creates a sub-directory every 250 files and moves the files to a sub-directory. If you have 1000 files, they will be moved to 4 sub-directories named 1, 2, 3 and 4. If you have 1001 files, a 5th subdir will be created for the last file.

```
cd YOUR_BIG_DIR
n=250                  # will change destination dir after 250 files
dir=1; mkdir -p $dir   # create first destination sub-directory "1"

ls -1 | while read f; do ((c+=1)); echo mv "$f" $dir/; [ $((c % n)) -eq 0 ] && ((dir+=1)) && mkdir -vp $dir; done
```

If the output looks like what you want, remove `echo` from the command to really `mv` the files.

The same command, explained, and without the "echo" used for testing:

```
# list all files, 1 per line
ls -1 \ 
| while read f; do # with each file "$f"
    ((c+=1))          # increase file counter
    mv "$f" $dir/     # move the file to $dir/

    # if counter c is a divisor of n, increase the directory number
    # and create the new destination directory
    [ $((c % n)) -eq 0 ] && ((dir+=1)) && mkdir -v -p $dir
  done
```

If you want sub-directories with a more exact size, then you would need to script something more sophisticated, using `stat -c %s` to get the size of each file or something similar.